# API Transition : From GraphQL to REST (with Django)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

For my current project (stack = [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) + API + [Vuejs](https://vuejs.org/)), up to now I used [GraphQL](https://graphql.org/) for my API (over Django, with [graphene-django](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-django)). But this library and other linked one (such as the one that handles [JWT](https://jwt.io/)s) are quite abandoned, with bugs and weird things so to be more confident in the future I decided to switch to the well-known [Django DRF](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/).

The thing is, I'm now quite used to GraphQL system of queries and mutations, which is (maybe because I'm used to it) quite simple in its design and when it comes to start with DRF, I feel kinda lost.

Indeed, I think I understood the easiest way is to use both [ModelSerializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer) and [ModelViewSet](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset) but... I feel it's hiding lots of things under the hood. Like it has default methods (`list()`, `retrieve()`,...).

What if I want to controll all this by defining only the necessary ?
Moreover, I have really specific needs.

For instance, update is not just giving all the arguments, update the model and TADAAA.
For specific fields I have to perform specific actions. (e.g.: if a particular field is modified, send a mail,...)

Maybe the best way for my use case is to use simple views, I mean, like it is explained in the [Trade-offs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/6-viewsets-and-routers/#trade-offs-between-views-vs-viewsets), using function based views might be the closest way to what I did with GraphQL ?

1 function = 1 view (URL) ?

Is that it ?

Thanks in advance for your clarifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having explored [DRF](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) a little more, I've come to the idea that what is the closest to GraphQL approach (lots of custom methods for me) is to use [Function Based Views](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#function-based-views). Indeed, there is no hidden behavior or API methods behind this and I have complete control on the API.

Yes, there is extra work needed : writing the URLs myself for instance but, ["Explicit is better than implicit"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/#id2).

So 1 URL = 1 mutation/query for me. And I execute the same work behind.